# Write output of two different Hadoop jobs to same set of reducers

Tags: hadoop, n-gram

I have a scenario where I need to run two `Hadoop` jobs calculating `n-gram` statistics for two different corpora and make sure that they write each n-gram (and it's score) to the same reducer (so that in future I can read the data locally and compare and contrast two scores from two corpora). For e.g. if job `J1` executes one of its reducers on machine `M` and writes n-gram `N` locally, I would like job `J2` to also write n-gram `N` to the same machine `M`.

I know how to compute n-gram statistics for a corpora (for reference, one can refer to [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.76.1126) pubication from Google). I have also defined my custom partitioner (taking hash based on first two words in the n-gram). Now how do I make sure that two different runs of the same program (on two different corpora) end up writing corresponding output to the same reducers?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [MultipleInputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/MultipleInputs.html).  By pointing two sibling mappers against sibling datasets you can avoid running an ID map on the combined set before reducing.